# websockets e php

Tags: php, websocket

Pois bem, eu tenho duas dúvidas diretas, que sao:

- é limitado o número de conexões ao servidor? o que limite isso? é possível ter conexões infinitas?
- Como eu poderia mandar mensagem para um determinado usuário de acordo com essa biblioteca?

Por exemplo existe `A`, `B`, `C` usuarios e eu queria mandar "Oi" pra `A` e nao pra `B e C`, nao entendi muito bem se esse script envia para o ID de acordo com o estabelecimento da conexao ou se ele usa o IP do conectado para enviar mensagem, veja o código que envia mensagens a todos:

```
foreach ( $Server->wsClients as $id => $client )
            if ( $id != $clientID )
                $Server->wsSend($id, "Visitor $clientID ($ip) said \"$message\"");
```

- é possível checar se a mensagem foi recebida? se sim, como eu posso checar se `A` recebeu mesmo a mensagem, ou se ela estava "offline"

Um exemplo, eu enviei "Oi" para `A` mas `A` nao estava conectada no servidor, ou nao recebeu a mensagem, como avisar a minha pessoa que essa mensagem nao pode ser entregue?

estou a usar esta biblioteca em PHP para fazer meu sistema funcionar: [GitHub](https://github.com/Flynsarmy/PHPWebSocket-Chat/blob/master/class.PHPWebSocket.php)

Comment: Dê uma lida na pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/61002/enviar-mensagem-para-usu%C3%A1rio-espec%C3%ADfico-em-websocket-php/98407#98407

Answer (score 1):

WebSockets mantém uma conexão persistente entre cliente e servidor. Não existe um limite escrito em pedra, mas o fato é que atender 10000 clientes com WebSockets vai exigir muito mais do servidor do que atender 10000 clientes com AJAX, porque no AJAX apenas uma pequena fração dos clientes está realmente conectada a cada momento.

O envio de mensagens é por ID, não por IP, cada ID representa uma conexão TCP/IP, pode haver várias pessoas conectadas no seu serviço que estão atrás de um mesmo roteador NAT. De alguma forma você vai ter de associar o ID com outra informação que identifique o cliente "A", "B" ou "C" (por exemplo, o cliente poderia mandar um nome assim que conecta?).

Para ter certeza que uma mensagem chegou ao cliente, o cliente deve mandar uma mensagem de "OK", no formato especificado por você. O método wsSend() retorna true quando os dados puderam ser enviados, mas isto não garante que o cliente recebeu, entendeu ou conseguiu processar a mensagem. (Por outro lado, se wsSend() retornar false, é garantido que o cliente não recebeu.)